# Cannot commit parts of *vc-diff* on Microsoft Windows

Tags: microsoft-windows, git, vc

Emacs has a beautiful feature: in the `*vc-diff*` buffer (generated by [`vc-diff`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Old-Revisions.html) either by <kbd>C-x v =</kbd> in a file buffer or by <kbd>=</kbd> in a `*vc-dir*` buffer), kill unwanted hunks with <kbd>k</kbd> (i.e., [`diff-hunk-kill`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Diff-Mode.html)) and then commit the remaining hunks with <kbd>C-x v v</kbd> (i.e., [`vc-next-action`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Basic-VC-Editing.html)). If you don't know about it -- try it, it is incredibly useful!

Alas, it does *not* work for me on windows: after <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> (i.e., [`log-edit-done`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Log-Buffer.html)) in `*vc-log*`, I get

> vc-do-command: Failed (status 1): c:/Users/ssteingold/AppData/Local/Git/bin/git.exe --no-pager apply --cached c:/msys64/tmp/git-patchPbbWgJ

and `*vc*` buffer is

```
error: patch failed: fxpy/model.py:1071
error: fxpy/model.py: patch does not apply
```

***Additionally***:

1. Software:

   - [`GNU Emacs 29.1 (build 2, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2023-08-02`](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/emacs-29/)
   - [`git version 2.42.0.windows.2`](https://gitforwindows.org/)
2. *normal* commits work just **fine**, using `vc-next-action` from either file buffer or `*vc-dir*`.
3. All my files have unix line terminators (`LF`) as indicated in the mode line as `(Unix)`
4. I set `autocrlf` to `false` globally
5. I have `(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)` in `.emacs`
6. `vc-coding-system-inherit-eol` is `t`, I did not touch it
7. When I add `"-v"` to `git apply` invocation in `vc-git-checkin` (`vc-git.el`), `*vc*` buffer contains `error: while searching for:.....` and every line in `.....` is terminated with `?` - which seems to indicate line-ending problems... (!!!)

***Q***: how do I fix this?
(This is a work box, I cannot send email from Emacs, so I cannot even file an Emacs bug report!)

Comment: Can't you send a bug report from some other computer? It's just an email - doesn't have to be composed in Emacs or sent from Emacs.

Comment: @Drew: okay, I [did](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=68377), and drew ire from Eli ;-(  -- on the positive side, according to Dmitry, it has been fixed in the trunk.

Comment: It should be fixed for the upcoming 29.2 as well (the `emacs-29` branch). Would be nice if you found the time to double-check, though.

Comment: @Dmitry: I will - as soon as there is a binary for me to download.

Comment: @sds I think it's now there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the answer from a comment: this should be fixed in the upcoming Emacs 29.2.

Comment: Confirmed - the bug has indeed been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## work-around 1

Add

```
(setq coding-system-for-write 'utf-8-unix)
```

inside `(with-temp-file patch-file ...)` in `vc-git-checkin`

## work-around 2

Add

```
;; replace `undecided`:
(setf (cadr (assoc "" file-coding-system-alist)) 'utf-8-unix)
```

to `.emacs`

## Emacs bug

`vc-git-checkin` should respect `vc-coding-system-inherit-eol` and set [`coding-system-for-write`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Specifying-Coding-Systems.html) when writing the patch.

Also, it does not seem reasonable that [`prefer-coding-system`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Output-Coding.html) does not affect [`file-coding-system-alist`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Default-Coding-Systems.html).

On the positive side, apparently [this bug](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=68377) has already been fixed in the development tree.